# Multiple Search function through array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to search through a list of multiple values.

Here is the an example of the values:

```
[
    {
    "color":"blue",
    "medium":"Sculpture",
    "place":"Garage"
    }
    {
    "color":"red",
    "medium":"Painting",
    "place":"Pool"
    }
]
```

Below is my code. Works great to find a single value. But I need to find multiple values. For example I need to look and find the results for queries such as: "red blue" or "blue Painting".

It should return results that have both word.

I don't really know how to solve this, does anybody have an idea?
Thanks a lot

```
function search(){
    var search = $('#search').val();
    if(search.length < 1) {
      return null;
    };

    var searches = search.split(" ");
    var fields = ["color","medium","place"]; 
    var results = [];

    $.each(searches, function(i, word){
      var wordResult = searchInJson(word,fields,json);
      if( wordResult.length > 0 ) {
        results.push(wordResult);
      }
    });

    var results = searchInJson(searches,fields,json);
    displaySearchResults(results);
};

function searchInJson(search,fields,json) {
    var regex = new RegExp(search);
    var results = [];
    $.each(json, function(i, image){
      $.each(fields, function(j, fieldname){

        var field = image[fieldname];
        if (regex.test(field)) {
          results.push( image );
        }
      });
    });
    return results;
}
```

Comment: That's an array of objects and not [JSON](http://json.org)

Comment: Why are you building up `results` and then completely overwriting it?

Comment: so what should the results be?  blue painting - return results that have either word or both?

Comment: It should return results that have both word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick method to try:

```js
var list = [
    {
    "color":"blue",
    "medium":"Sculpture",
    "place":"Garage"
    },
    {
    "color":"red",
    "medium":"Painting",
    "place":"Pool"
    }
];

var search = "red painting";

var results = list.filter(function (el) {
  var s = search.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  for (var key in el) {
    for (var i=0; i < s.length; i++) {
      if (el[key].toLowerCase() == s[i]) {  // this could use indexOf depending on if you want to match partial words
        s.splice(i,1);
        i--;
        if (!s.length) return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Yes it works, thanks a lot! Some values are made of two words, for example: "The Place". The code above doesn't seem to work on this case. do you know how I can do that? Thanks again!

Comment: See my note on indexOf, the if would change to `if (el[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(s[i]) != -1)`.  However if you search on "rage" you will get "Garage".

Comment: Ok, this is great. Thanks !